# DPKG: Error Processing (--unpack) (RaspberryPi Compiler - Ubuntu)

Tags: dpkg

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/RaspberryPi/devel$ sb2 -eR apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
alsa-base gnome-themes-standard lxde lxsession openssh-client openssh-server scratch wpasupplicant
The following packages will be upgraded:
alsa-utils apt apt-utils aptitude aptitude-common base-files bash binutils bsdutils bzip2 ca-certificates console-setup
console-setup-linux consolekit coreutils cpio cpp cpp-4.6 cryptsetup-bin curl dbus dbus-x11 dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service
debconf debconf-i18n debconf-utils debian-reference-common debian-reference-en desktop-base dictionaries-common dmsetup dpkg
dpkg-dev e2fslibs e2fsprogs eject file firmware-atheros firmware-brcm80211 firmware-libertas firmware-ralink firmware-realtek
fontconfig fontconfig-config fuse g++ g++-4.6 gcc gcc-4.4-base gcc-4.6 gcc-4.6-base gcc-4.7-base gconf-service gconf2
gconf2-common gdb gdbserver gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10 gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gnupg gpgv gsettings-desktop-schemas idle
idle-python2.7 idle-python3.2 idle3 ifupdown initscripts insserv iptables isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common iso-codes
keyboard-configuration kmod krb5-locales libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg-dev libapt-pkg4.12 libasound2 libavahi-client3
libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libblkid1 libboost-iostreams1.49.0 libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev
libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcap2 libck-connector0 libcomerr2 libcroco3 libcryptsetup4 libcups2 libcurl3 libdbus-1-3
libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libdconf0 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdpkg-perl libdrm2 libelf1 libexpat1
libexpat1-dev libfm-data libfm-gtk-bin libfm-gtk1 libfm1 libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libfuse2
libgail-3-0 libgail18 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgcrypt11 libgfortran3 libgif4 libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0
libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglib2.0-dev libgnutls26 libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0
libgtk2.0-common libgudev-1.0-0 libicu-dev libicu48 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjson0 libk5crypto3
libkmod2 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 liblapack3 liblapack3gf libldap-2.4-2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblvm2app2.2 liblzma5 libmagic1
libmikmod2 libmount1 libnewt0.52 libnfnetlink0 libobrender27 libobt0 libopenjpeg2 libpam-ck-connector libparted0debian1 libpci3
libpcsclite1 libpixman-1-0 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libportmidi0 libprocps0 libproxy0
libpulse0 libpython2.7 libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc libraspberrypi0 libreadline6 librsvg2-2
librsvg2-common libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsdl-mixer1.2 libsmpeg0 libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev libss2 libssh2-1 libssl-dev
libssl1.0.0 libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.6-dev libsysfs2 libsystemd-login0 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff4 libudev-dev libudev0
libusb-0.1-4 libuuid1 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwebp2
libwrap0 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libxapian-dev libxapian22 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb1 libxcursor1
libxext6 libxfixes3 libxfont1 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxml2 libxml2-dev libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxres1 libxslt1-dev libxslt1.1
libxt6 libxtst6 libxxf86vm1 lightdm linux-libc-dev locales lsb-base lua5.1 lxde-core lxtask manpages midori module-init-tools
mount multiarch-support net-tools nfs-common ntfs-3g omxplayer openbox openssh-blacklist openssh-blacklist-extra openssl parted
pciutils perl perl-base perl-modules policykit-1 procps psmisc python python-minimal python-numpy python-pygame python2.7
python2.7-minimal python3 python3-minimal python3-numpy python3.2 python3.2-minimal raspberrypi-bootloader raspi-copies-and-fills
readline-common rsyslog samba-common sgml-base squeak-vm ssh sudo sysv-rc sysvinit sysvinit-utils tar tasksel tasksel-data tcpd
ttf-dejavu-core tzdata udev udisks unzip util-linux vim-common vim-tiny wget whiptail x11-common xarchiver xkb-data xml-core
xserver-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xz-utils
319 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 269 MB of archives.
After this operation, 23.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Fetched 269 MB in 2min 11s (2,043 kB/s) 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 54465 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace base-files 6.9 (using .../base-files_7.1wheezy2+rpi1_armhf.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement base-files ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_7.1wheezy2+rpi1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/var/run', which is also in package isc-dhcp-client 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_7.1wheezy2+rpi1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/RaspberryPi/devel$
```

Im was using this "How to..." FAQ http://www.pieczewski.de/programming/RaspberryPi_CrossCompile

Hope you can help me.

Comment: What does `sb2 -eR apt-get upgrade` command means?

Comment: its the same like "sudo apt-get upgrade"
but its only for the raspberry pi compiler

Comment: Remove `isc-dhcp-client` package by running `sudo apt-get purge isc-dhcp-client` and then do an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, but its works with only sb2 -eR apt-get purge isc-dhcp-client for me :)

Comment: My next problem:

`Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/raspi-copies-and-fills_0.4-1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: please post the full error report in pastebin.com and provide the link here.

Comment: I´wil... but not network connection on virtual machine where is my ubuntu installed

Comment: did you able to post the second error on your question?

Comment: No... No network... I think its because isc-dhcp-client

Comment: did you had another ubuntu pc or ubuntu live disk?If yes then boot from it.Connect to the internet and run these commands `sudo apt-get update` and `apt-get download isc-dhcp-client`.The second command will download the corresponding `isc-dhcp-client.deb` file in your home directory.Then copy the .deb file and install it on your pc by running `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`

Comment: Dont help... No network.. and I cant do anything

Comment: did you downloaded the .deb file?Please reply quickly.

Comment: So, okey.. I have solved this problem.

Comment: How did you do that?Did you follow my above comment?

Comment: Now the link "pastebin" :)
pastebin.com/Tme1kJA7

Comment: How did you got the internet working?

Comment: I just edited sudo `nano /etc/network/interfaces` to `auto eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp` and then `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: Okey, I will start a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the previously installed `isc-dhcp-client` package by running,

```
sb2 -eR apt-get purge isc-dhcp-client
```

And then do an upgrade,

```
sb2 -eR apt-get upgrade
```